# Page numbering, book class

Tags: page-numbering, fancyhdr, books

So in the default book class, the page number for chapters appears at the bottom of the page. I just want the page numbering to alternate left and right, as it does for all other pages.

How can I change the different behavior for pages where there is a chapter?

I have googled the problem and I am aware the package fancyhdr may be of some use, but I don't understand how to use it (yes I read some of the documentation and I still don't understand). So far I just use its default behavior:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\Stuff
\end{document}
```

EDIT:
I want the page numbers to appear in the header. I've changed the code to look like this:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}

\begin{document}
\Stuff
\end{document}
```

What this does is to alternate the pages depending on whether it is odd or even, but for chapters, the pages are still centered. Also, I now have page numbers listed in BOTH the header AND the footer for ALL pages...

Comment: I see you are a new user. Welcome! Now, if your book is fiction (rather than academic, or math), consider using the `novel` document class, instead of `book`. Many of the problems you are likely to face, are internally solved within this class. For example, `fancyhdr` is pre-configured with several menu choices, optimized for fiction (including the one you want). The `novel` package is not shipped with TeX; you have to get it via your TeX package manager.

Comment: See \fancypagestyle{plain} on pages 7 & 8 of the fancyhdr manual.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

The letters in square brackets tell you, which position in the header or footer the contents of the curly brackets will be positioned in. L, R, C are left, right, and center, O and E are odd and even. So `\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}` will print the current page number cnetered in the footer. It might be useful to have a look at the documentation.

After your edit, I’d recommend you clear all headers and footers in the pagestyle `fancy` with `\fancyhf{}` and redefine the pagestyle `plain` that is used by the `\chapter`-command with `\fancypagestyle`:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}%clear all headers and footers
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}

\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhf{}%clear all headers and footers
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%header rule invisible
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Stuff}
\lipsum
\section{More stuff}
\lipsum
\chapter{Different stuff}
\lipsum
\section{Different stuff in a section}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, this didn't work. I also wanted the pages to appear in the header. I will add some further comments in my original post, give me a few minutes

Comment: Without option twoside this code doesn't work! \documentclass[twoside]{book}

Comment: The book class uses the option `twoside` by default. There is no need to specify it explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

I found what I was looking for. Put this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RO]{\slshape \rightmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\slshape \leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO,RE]{\thepage}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\cfoot{} % get rid of the page number 
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}
```

As far as I understand it, the code below changes the pagestyle of Chapter from plain to fancy.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox} 
\patchcmd{\chapter}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{\thispagestyle{fancy}}{}{}
```

You can clear the page numbers from the footer using:

```
\cfoot{}
```

You can adjust the width of the lines by changing the number (or remove them by putting 0pt):

```
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
```

Thanks for the help.