# How can I keep the place of page numbering in the footer while using `documentclass{book}`?

Tags: header-footer, page-numbering, books, book-design, footer

Here is my document from the beginning:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tocloft}

\usepackage{titlesec}

\begin{document}
   
    \newgeometry{top=1.75in,hmargin=1in, bottom=1in} 
    
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
```

And here is the part that when I added to the document the numbering of the pages changed from the footer to the header (left and right alternatively):

```
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
  {\titleline{}\vspace{5pt}\titleline{}\vspace{1pt}%
  \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
  {1pc}
  {\titleline{}\vspace{0.5pc}}



\chapter{BIOLOGICAL STRUCTURE}

The main results of this chapter is to give 
\section{PRELIMINARIES}
```

I also wanted to say that I used to use `documentclass{article}` when my numbering was in the footer.

Can anyone tell me please what changed the place of the page numbering? and how can I keep the `documentclass{book}` and keep the page numbers in the footer?

Comment: It wasn't the use of `\titleformat` that changed the location. It was changing from `\documentclass{article}` to `\documentclass{book}` that changed the location of the page numbers. However, if you're using `\pagenumbering{gobble}`, there should be no page numbers.

Comment: Yeah some pages I do not want them to contain numbers @Werner ......  but how can I keep the page number in the footer while also using the `documentclass{book}` do you have any suggestions for that?

Comment: But the purpose of `gobble` is to remove page numbers.  Is there a reason you're using it if you want page numbers?  Regardless, part of `\chapter` calls `\thispagestyle{empty}`, which removes the page numbers.  If you follow your `\chapter` command with `\thispagestyle{plain}` (or whatever you're using), it should return.  I think.

Comment: I am removing page numbers from the first three pages of my document, but then I want roman number and then Arabic numbers.@Teepeemm maybe my code contain some redundant parts, correct me please if this is the case.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Page numbering, book class](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/403565/page-numbering-book-class)

Comment: @M.A.Bromuela I read it thoroughly, but unfortunately, it did not answer my question.

Comment: you just replace `fancyhead` with `fancyfoot` for the page numbers.

Comment: You might also look at the \frontmatter and \mainmatter commands for book class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This shows how to do it without fancyhdr.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}% avoid if possible
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
  {\titleline{}\vspace{5pt}\titleline{}\vspace{1pt}%
  \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
  {1pc}
  {\titleline{}\vspace{0.5pc}}

\makeatletter
\def\ps@headings{%
      \def\@oddfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}%
      \def\@evenfoot{\normalfont\hfil\thepage\hfil}}
      \def\@evenhead{\hfil\slshape\leftmark}%
      \def\@oddhead{{\slshape\rightmark}\hfil%
      \let\@mkboth\markboth
    \def\chaptermark##1{%
      \markboth {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
          \if@mainmatter
            \@chapapp\ \thechapter. \ %
          \fi
        \fi
        ##1}}{}}%
    \def\sectionmark##1{%
      \markright {\MakeUppercase{%
        \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\z@
          \thesection. \ %
        \fi
        ##1}}}}
\makeatother
\pagestyle{headings}% apply new definitions
  
\usepackage{lipsum}% random text

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\begin{titlepage}
\vspace*{0.75in}% assuming one page only
Note that \verb|\maketitle| is optional.
\end{titlepage}
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Title}
\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

And this shows how to do with `fancyhdr`. (It can be frustrating some times to use this, so beware!). You control how the page numbers are displayed in the odd and even pages using the options `L` and `R` for left side and right side and `O` and `E` for odd and even pages. Keep in mind that, usually odd pages are to the right and even pages are to the left of a book. So the options `RO, LE` were passed to the `fancyfoot`. Also by default, the page number at the beginning of a chapter is in the center of the footer. To change that, you must redefine the `plain` page style. So the full code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twoside]{book}

%\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % Usually you don't need it. So I commented this out.

\usepackage[a4paper, margin=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace} % John Kormylo suggests you avoid this if possible.
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\usepackage{titlesec}
 \titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\LARGE\bfseries}
  {\titleline{}\vspace{5pt}\titleline{}\vspace{1pt}%
  \MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename} \thechapter}
  {1pc}
  {\titleline{}\vspace{0.5pc}}
  
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[RE, LO]{\thepage}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\chapter{Preface}
\lipsum[1-2]

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chap 1}
\section{Sec 1}
\lipsum[3-30]
\chapter{Chap 1}
\section{Sec 1}
\lipsum[4]

\backmatter
\lipsum[7-8]
\end{document}
```

The beginning of a chapter would have its page numbered in the center of the footer like this:

[image: Beginning of a chapter]

In case you want to make page numbers appear everywhere as usual then you can add additional commands just after `fancyhdr` definitions:

```
\fancypagestyle{plain}{
\fancyhf{}
\fancyfoot[LE,RO]{\thepage}}
```

The next few pages of a chapter shall look like this:

[image: Next page of chapter]

Lastly, if you don't want page numbers to show up in some pages then you can use `\thispagestyle{empty}` followed by a `\clearpage` command where you want the page to end and begin another page.